# Android app crashes while starting next activity from different thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to process some db operations and after that want to start a new activity. Meanwhile, I want progress bar to display.

The code I written below is working fine on android studio as well as on some devices, but on some devices, app is getting crashed when starting new activity from thread. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
    progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setMessage("Prepairing relations...");
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sql.updateRelations();   // db operations

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            progress.dismiss();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    t1.start();
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your new activity from the main thread using a handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:-

```
progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Prepairing relations..."); 
progress.setProgress(0); 
progress.setCancelable(false); 
progress.show(); 

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sql.updateRelations();   // db operations 
        Intent intent = new Intent(NameActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        progress.dismiss(); 
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}, 15000);
```